# JQuery UI datepicker "dialog" not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I cannot seem to get the datepicker with the "dialog" option set to work in IE 8, works everywhere else but in IE8 it says

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 4 Feb 2014 23:19:02 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 974
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://dev.site.com/page
```

This is the line it is referencing.

```
root.datepicker('dialog',root.text().trim(),function(date){
 root.text(date);
 saveCourseDate(root);
},{
 altFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
 dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

`root` is a jquery object of a span tag. Works fine in other browsers though.

It is not a jquery IU issue as far as I can see as on the same page i have another date picker without the dialog option and it works.

```
jQuery('#course_date').datepicker({altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

The site I am doing is enterprise level, so IE8 is an absolute must. I have tried to search for this issue and although I see topics on IE 8 problems with jquery ui, none seem to match  this.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a problem with jQuery UI; `String.trim` isn't available in IE8: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim - use jQuery's `$.trim()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/, add one to `String`'s prototype, or make a generic function (like jQuery's)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your two snippets of code is the `root.text().trim()` part. That doesn't work in IE8 because `String.prototype.trim` isn't defined in IE8; support starts in IE9.

Since you have jQuery, you might as well use its utility function `$.trim()`. You would use it like:

```
root.datepicker('dialog',$.trim(root.text()),function(date){
```

Your other options are to extend `String.prototype` and add a method yourself, like:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = (function () {
        var re, ret;
        re = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
        ret = function () {
            return this.replace(re, "");
        };
        return ret;
    }());
}
```

That way, you could keep your original code. If you use this, make sure it's executed before your problematic code.

Or just take that code and make it a function you can call like `$.trim()`. I personally like to use jQuery's function or my own function (not extending the prototype). In the case where the value is actually `null` or `undefined`...then it throws an error. `$.trim` accounts for this (as well as a user-defined function could)

References:

- `String.prototype.trim` compatibility: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim
- `$.trim()`: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim

Comment: Nice! yea didn't even think of that. I'll give it a go and see if this is the solution (pretty sure it is).